# При нажатии на Отмену массив input file очищается

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input

Есть `<input type='file' name='files[]'>`
Нажав на кнопку "Загрузить" я загружаю, например, 2-3 картинки: выходит файл селектор, где я выбираю файлы, кликаю "Ок". Потом я захочу загрузить еще одну картинку. Нажимаю "Загрузить" и тут, не выбрав ни одну, я нажимаю на кнопку "Отмена" и все в массиве `files[]` стирается, то есть 2-3 картинки, которые до этого загрузил пропали. Что делать?
Пытался создать отдельный массив `var uploadedFiles = [];` и перемещать туда уже загруженные, а потом перед отправкой формы на сервер, присвоить мой массив к массиву input: `$("#myDiv").find("input").files = uploadedFiles;`

Answer (score 1):

Вы никак не можете сохранить файлы не загруженные на сервер которые получаете в момент `change` у `input type="file"`. Очевидно, что вам необходимо отправлять форму с файлом или отправлять `ajax` используя `FormData`, но иногда нет смысла сразу загружать выбранный файл и нужно дождаться нажатия кнопки "Отправить". И в приведенном вами кейсе (как вы хотели бы) будет непонятно, как мне выбрать только одну новую картинку т.к. в первый раз я мог ошибиться с выбором файла по этому и по соображениям безопасности, возможность загрузить без ведома пользователя файл по ошибке выбранный в предыдущий раз нельзя.